# Azure Application Insights for monitoring SQL Queries

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to get the SQL queries from an Azure App Service sent to Application Insights.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39419283/214980), I ran the dependencies check in the analytics, and got sdk Version `rddf:2.5.0-49733`. So now I need to install Status Monitor - but isn't that for IIS hosting? If I'm running it on Azure as an App Service, then what do I need to do?

This is what I'm currently seeing:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get full SQL Queries for your app running in Azure WebApps, install the 'Application Insights' extension in your web app. Please restart the app service after installing the extension. 
This will enable collection of full SQL statements.

(Enabling profiling does more profiling of your code, but if your only goal is to get SQL queries, installing extension is all you need assuming instrumentation key is set correctly)

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing is, you have to enable the Profiler in Azure, for that Application Insights instance. Click the `Enable Profiler` button:

[image]

You'll need to have your app in a Basic Service Plan or higher. Mine was in the Free tier, and it wouldn't work. I had to upgrade to Basic to enable the Profiler. Make sure the profiler is started.

Then I had to link my app, although this might happen automatically.

[image]

Took a bit of fiddling to get this done I had to Re-install, and `Add Instrumentation Key` (from the menu in the ellipsis).

Finally, it worked:

[image]

SDK version is also now:    `rddp:2.5.0-49733`