# Not collect SQL dependencies in TEST environment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, azure-application-insights

I published my project, which uses Application Insights, on an IIS server. The files I published are: all DLL from Application Insights, the script tag for collects http requests from the view that i want to track, and the applicationInsights.config with the intrssumentation key  in it.

The issue is that not collect SQL dependencies. But the interesting thing is that when I run the project in Visual Studio it collects all the dependencies including the SQL dependencies.

In this case, what could be the problem? a configuration issue on the server? something missing from publish to server?

Comment: try to install Status Monitor to collect dependency details. assign iis_iusrs permission to the temp and app_data local folder and restart iis after doing all the changes. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410598/application-insights-not-tracking-sql-queries)

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing them collected locally while debugging, but *not* when deployed, then chances are you have a different version of .net or the AI sdks installed in the 2 places, or you're missing a required library when you deploy?  make sure your deployed items are the same as your local dependencies?

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/auto-collect-dependencies

for a bunch of the details about versions and packages, etc.